# Skipping intermediary constructors in a java Jar

Tags: java, jar

I am attempting to extend a class in a Java jar that has a constructor that allows it to copy properties, however I am running into a problem where I need to use the base implementation but the types in the intermediary steps are preventing what I need to do.

Here are the relevant portions of each class (this first block are all in Jars that I cannot modify)

```
public class Player
{
  public Player (Player player)
  {
      //  do all the copying
  {
}

public class ComputerPlayer extends Player
{
  public ComputerPlayer(ComputerPlayer player)
  {
      super(player);
  {
}

public class MiniMaxPlayer extends ComputerPlayer
{
  public MiniMaxPlayer(MiniMaxPlayer player)
  {
      super(player);
  {
}

public class HumanPlayer extends Player
{
  public HumanPlayer(HumanPlayer player)
  {
      super(player);
  {
}
```

Now I am trying to create a simulated player for MonteCarlo simulations.  The game will contain other MonteCarloPlayers OR HumanPlayers.  I need the base player stuff to be copied.

Currently MonteCarloPlayer extends MiniMaxPlayer because I want it to default to MiniMax for certain move types that I haven't implemented.  However I run into the same problem when I extend ComputerPlayer

```
public class MonteCarloPlayer extends MiniMaxPlayer
{
  public MonteCarloPlayer(Player player)
  {
      super(player);
  {
}

public class SimulatedMCPlayer extends MonteCarloPlayer 
{
  public SimulatedMCPlayer (Player player)
  {
      super(player);
  {
}
```

The problem is, since SimulatedMCPlayer could be copying either a HumanPlayer or a MonteCarloPlayer the constructors for the extended classes don't work.  I either need to bypass those constructors OR somehow modify the classes with new constructors.  I've been searching and the only solution I can find to modify jar classes is to extend them, which doesn't solve the problem

I've tried doing the copying directly in MonteCarloPlayer, but the problem is some of the fields are final or protected (including some of the most important ones like UUID) so that doesn't work either.

I appreciate any ideas that could steer me in the right direction.

Comment: Hint: are you sure that you need such sophisticated inheritance trees? There are good reasons to **favor composition over inheritance**. You know, maybe some of your players should not extend other players, but just **own** a player object?

Comment: The ones in the .jar are not mine.  I'm just trying to code a new AI for a game.  I can't really work around that.

The game state that runs all the rules requires the player objects.  I suppose I could use MonteCarloPlayer to extend Player directly - but that will currently break all game decisions I haven't yet implemented.

For Monte Carlo simulation I need to copy the information over so that the simulated game treats them the same as another player but without modifying the players directly.  Even if players own a player object I still run into the same problem.

Comment: Oooh That would be interesting.  If my simulatedplayer owned a player object I think that would help skirt the issue.  I'd have to pretty much override every method to the Player object field though.  Or maybe I could create a HashMap<Player> on the Monte Carlo Node.. no that won't work because then the Game would have no way of knowing to use the MonteCarlo AI.

Comment: All I am saying is: consider reviewing your design; maybe together with real people around you. Typically, bad designs don't improve when trying to stuff more functionality into them.

Comment: If I had 'real people around me' I wouldn't be posting here.  I could post on the game's forums telling them that they've got bad design but I doubt they will change it just for me.  Telling me that the source I'm working with is badly designed doesn't help (even though it's true).  How do I make this work with what I have?

Comment: The thing is: I don't know your environment. Many people come here, completely forgetting that they also have peers, coworkers, friends around who might be able to help as well. And I am also not telling you that everything you are dealing with is **bad**. All I am saying is that it looks like you could benefit from actions such as reviews. Finally - please understand that such kind of design reviews/improvement questions actually do not have a place here (to a certain degree).

Comment: Okay, I figured out a way to do it.  There is a constructor that takes the UUID (the only 'final class') on Player and ComputerPlayer, but not on the MiniMax player.

Then there is a method on player (called restore) that copies all the values of one player onto another player.

So extending ComputerPlayer and restoring the values achieves basically what I'm looking for.

Yes, you are right though.  The information you gave me does give me information on how to improve my own code to avoid this situation in the my own work.  I apologize if I got a little antsy.